# Not able to submit html form from Objective C UIWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, forms, uiwebview

am adding form values like this

```
<form method='post' action='' name=
  'f' id="f">
<input type='hidden' id='EMAIL' name='EMAIL' value='' />'
<input type='hidden' id='MOBILE'name='MOBILE' value='' />'
</form>
```

Am inserting values to this form using

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

    updateEmail = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementById('EMAIL').value='%@';",[self.objModel valueForKey:@"email"]];
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:updateEmail];


    mobile = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementById('MOBILE').value='%@';",[self.objModel valueForKey:@"mobile"]];
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:mobile];


//Submit form
  NSString *submitButton = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementById('f').submit();"];
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:submitButton];

//but this is not working

formAction = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementById('f').action='%@';",[self.objModel valueForKey:@"actionUrl"]];

    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:checkumhash];



}
```

I can see my values are inserted correctly to html form but its not getting submitted.
i think my form submitting part is not working. when i fill this form in run on browser (normal chrome) its working fine. But its not working while loading from app browser.

pls help to clear this

UPDATE :

I have noticed that "Form Action url is not getting inserted " please check the screenshot[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUonz.png)